# How to use Extension methods in Powershell?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, extension-methods

I have the following code:

```
using System;

public static class IntEx
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Yields a power of the given number
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="number">The base number</param>
    /// <param name="powerOf">the power to be applied on te base number</param>
    /// <returns>Powers applied to  the base number</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<int> ListPowersOf(this int number, int powerOf)
    {
        for (var i = number; ; i <<= powerOf)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

I've loaded the dll in Powershell(Windows 8). I try to use it the following way:

```
$test = 1.ListPowersOf(2)
```

Should return @(1, 2, 4, 8, 16...)

Instead, it says there is no such method.

I tried the following:

```
[BaseDllNamespace]::ListPowersOf(1,2)
```

Still nothing. I have no namespace in the IntEx class.

How do I make it work

Comment: Take a look here, it may helps you [EXTENSION METHODS IN WINDOWS POWERSHELL](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2007/09/06/extension-methods-in-windows-powershell.aspx)

Comment: The C# code doesn't compile and doesn't work. You're missing a `;` at the end of `using System` and there should be a `using System.Collections.Generic;`.  And the code results in an infinite loop.  You could replace the whole `for` loop with just `yield return (int)Math.Pow(number, powerOf);`.

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```powershell
[IntEx]::ListPowersOf(1,2)
```

or

```powershell
[IntEx] | gm -Static -Type Method
```

to list available static methods.

You can also use reflection to obtain list of exported types to see if yours is available:

```powershell
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('C:path\to.dll')|select -ExpandProperty ExportedTypes
```

Comment: Nice. Just to spell it out: while PowerShell doesn't allow you to call extension methods directly, on an _instance_ of a type for which it is defined, you can call them as _static_ methods on the _type_, and pass the instance as the 1st argument.

Answer (score 10):

I realize this isn't likely to apply to OP at this point, but this question was the first result for my search so I'll post what I figured out here.

I'm pretty surprised this one isn't already mentioned, but CodeMethods in PowerShell are essentially compiled extension methods for a given type. They're pretty easy to write, too - especially when you already have the extension method.

```
public static class MyStringExtensions
{
    public static string Append(this string source, params char[] characters)
    {
        foreach (var c in characters)
        {
            source += c;
        }
        return source;
    }
    // named PSAppend instead of Append. This is just a naming convention I like to use,
    // but it seems some difference in name is necessary if you're adding the type data 
    // via a types.ps1xml file instead of through the Update-TypeData command
    public static string PSAppend(PSObject source, params char[] characters)
    {
        if (source.BaseObject is string sourceString)
        {
            return sourceString.Append(characters);
        }
        else throw new PSInvalidOperationException();
    }
    private static string Example() {
        var myString = "Some Value.";
        Console.WriteLine(myString.Append(" and then some more.".ToCharArray()));
        // console output: 
        // Some Value. and then some more.
    }
}
```

After loading the type definition into PowerShell:

```
$method = [MyStringExtensions].GetMethod('PSAppend')
Update-TypeData -TypeName System.String -MemberName Append -MemberType CodeMethod -Value $method
# now you can use the method the same way you'd use an extension method in C#
PS:\> $myString = "Some Value."
PS:\> $myString.Append(" and then some more.")
Some value. and then some more.
```

[Documentation for code methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/defining-default-methods-for-objects?view=powershell-7.1#code-methods) is less than ideal. If you're building this into a module and defining a CodeMethod in your Types.ps1xml file referenced by your manifest (.psd1), you'll need to include the assembly that defines the code method in the `RequiredAssemblies` of the manifest. (Including it as `RootModule` is insufficient because the assemblies of the type(s) must be loaded before the type file(s) are loaded.)

Here's how you'd include this type definition in a Types.ps1xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Types>
    <Type>
        <Name>System.String</Name>
        <Members>
            <CodeMethod>
                <Name>Append</Name>
                <CodeReference>
                    <TypeName>MyStringExtensions</TypeName>
                    <MethodName>PSAppend</MethodName>
                </CodeReference>
            </CodeMethod>
        </Members>
    </Type>
</Types>
```

Comment: FYI: Placed your code in a PowerShell `Add-Type -Language 'CSharp' -TypeDefinition @'<csharp code>'@` and couldn't get it to work until changing PSAppend to this: `public static string PSAppend(PSObject source, params char[] characters) { if (source.BaseObject is string) { return ((string)source.BaseObject).Append(characters); } else throw new PSInvalidOperationException(); }`

Comment: @Darin Great point - Windows PowerShell doesn't allow some of the newer C# features I've used in my example. Thanks for providing more compatible code.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want it to read closer to dot syntax, you could use an implicit or explicit conversion operator on your `IntEx` type and use it as a POCO instead of as a static extension.

It might look something like this...

```
$code=@'
public class MyExtClass {

    public string TheStringValue {get; set;}

    public MyExtClass(string theString){
        TheStringValue = theString;
    }

    public int NumberOf(string target)
    {
        return TheStringValue.Length - TheStringValue.Replace(target, "").Length;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyExtClass(string value){
        return new MyExtClass(value);
    }
}
'@
add-type -TypeDefinition $code

$str_eee = "TheTheThe"
$numberOfEs = ([MyExtClass]$str_eee).NumberOf("e")

if(3 -eq $numberOfEs){Write-Host PASS; exit 0}

Write-Host "FAIL";
exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pure PowerShell Version of Stroniax's answer

The following class defines the methods `Prefix` and `Suffix`, which are meant to be used with `System.String` type, and the method `AddTypeMember` which can be used to add any existing, and properly designed, method to an existing type.  The primary design requirement for a method is that the first parameter **must** be of type `PSObject`, and I believe it needs to be `static`.

```
class MyExtensions {
   static [string]Prefix([PSObject]$source, [string]$prefix) {
      return "$prefix$source"
   }
   static [string]Suffix([PSObject]$source, [string]$suffix) {
      return "$source$suffix"
   }
   static [void]AddTypeMember([string]$typeName, [string]$MemberName) {
      Update-TypeData -TypeName $typeName -MemberName $MemberName -MemberType CodeMethod -Value ([MyExtensions].GetMethod($MemberName))
   }
}
```

To add methods to a type, use the `AddTypeMember` method.  The following example commands add to `System.String` the methods `Prefix` and `Suffix`.

```
[MyExtensions]::AddTypeMember('System.String', 'Prefix')
[MyExtensions]::AddTypeMember('System.String', 'Suffix')
```

Once properly defined, you can now used the `Prefix` and `Suffix` methods as in the following example:

```
'mark'.Prefix('re')
'mark'.Suffix('able')
'mark'.Prefix('re').Suffix('able')
```

Which produces this output:

```
remark
markable
remarkable
```